# PowerShell script trying to copy folders that do not exist

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to copy "Documents" folder to my OneDrive using a PowerShell script, but I am having an error. It's trying to copy the folders "My Pictures", "My Music" and "My Videos" assuming they are inside the "Documents" folder, but there is no such folder in there (it's copying other folders and file normally). I am using Windows 10.

The command I used:

```
 Copy-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents" -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive" -Recurse -Force
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those folders exist. You can view them with `Get-ChildItem -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Documents -Force`. Output (excerpt):

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d--hsl       16.05.2020     14:32                My Music
d--hsl       16.05.2020     14:32                My Pictures
d--hsl       16.05.2020     14:32                My Videos
```

As you can see, they are hidden system symbolic links to directories. You cannot tell `Copy-Item` to omit them, but you can do it using `robocopy`:

```bsh
robocopy $env:USERPROFILE\Documents $env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive /e /xj
```

- `/e` equivalent to `-Recurse` (to deep copy)
- `/xj` will exclude junctions (aka symbolic links)

[Read more about `robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Comment: You should be able to exclude those symbolic links using `-Exclude @("My Games", "My Music", "My Pictures", "My Videos")`

Comment: @JonathonAnderson It won't, because `-Exclude`/`-Include` filters are applied AFTER the objects have already been fetched (very inefficient btw.). So the access error will occur before the `-Exclude`/`-Include` filters have been applied.